# How to print a full line of text in java (from input file)

Tags: java, string, input, printing, newline

I'm trying to print each individual *line* of an external file, but I can only manage to print each individual *word*. Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter input filename: ");
  String inputFile = scnr.next();
  
  FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
  Scanner inFS = null; 
  
  fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
  
  while (inFS.hasNext()) {
     String resultToPrint = inFS.next();
     System.out.println(resultToPrint);
  }
```

So, for example, if the external .txt file is something like this:
THIS IS THE FIRST LINE.
(new line) THIS IS THE SECOND LINE.
(new line) THIS IS THE THIRD LINE.
...

Then right now it prints like this:
THIS
(new line) IS
(new line) THE
(new line) FIRST
(new line) LINE
(new line) THIS
(new line) IS
...

and I want it to print like how it appears in the original file.

Any suggestions on how to make each iteration of resultToPrint be a full line of text, as opposed to a single word? (I'm new to java, so sorry if the answer seems obvious!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
```

by

```
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream).useDelimiter( "\\n" );
```

This will set the "word" separator to the line feed character, making the full line a single "word".

Or use `java.nio.files.Files.lines()` …

Also `java.io.BufferedReader.lines()` would be a nice alternative …

Comment: Might need to be careful using `"\\n"` as that would be platform dependent, might want to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: @Nexevis – in this case, `\n` is a regex pattern, not the String escape for the line ending. If you will suggest something else, it should be "$".

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a file you need a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

Then use it's method [readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

This code reads every line of a file then prints it:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)))) {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and cleaner approach would be:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filename");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```

or

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```